# Duplicate posts and change category

Tags: posts, categories, duplicates

I am trying to create a button inside a post and, when the user clicks on it, I'd like the post to be duplicated and this new post goes to another category, is it possible?

For example: I have "post 1" in "category1". When the user clicks on the button "duplicate", it should duplicate the "post1" inside the "category2".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's plugin to do that - [Duplicate Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/duplicate-post/)

> While viewing a post as a logged in user, you can click on `Copy to a new draft` as a dropdown link under `Edit Post` in the admin bar. This will lead you to edit post page, change whatever you want and save. It'll save it as different post.

<sup>- Quote for plugin Description</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Postmenu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postmenu) plugin, because with it you can:

- Duplicate and advance duplicate to any post type: post, page, custom post page.
- Duplicate Menu.
- Easy add page to the menu link.
- Duplicate any terms like category, tags, and custom terms.
- Bulk Duplicate any post types and bulk Duplicate any terms.
- It has compatibility with WPML.

But in your case, you use the `Advance Duplicate` link and select what do you need duplicate.

For any additional information go to [the Plugin Description](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postmenu) or [Developer Page](https://liontude.com/postmenu-link-duplicate-posts-menus-wordpress/), I write more information because I use every day to my job.

I hope help you.